# List iterator returning zero

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, iterator

i am trying to iterate records from a table using the `list iterator` but it is returning `zero` records . i have used a setter getter class and trying to fetch records into a jsp page

code is as follows :

java function :

```
public List<product> getProducts()
{ 
   List<product> prod=new ArrayList<product>();
  try
  {
   conn = obj.connect();
   String sql="select product.product_name , product.price ,  product.image_url "
           + "from category , product "
           + "where product.category_id=category.category_id and   product.product_brand like 'LG%'";
     rs=cs.executeQuery(sql);
   while(rs.next())
   {
      p.setPname(rs.getString(1));
      p.setPrice(rs.getString(2));
      p.setImg(rs.getString(3));
   }
     prod.add(p);
  }

    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception k)
    {
        k.printStackTrace();
    }
  return prod;
}
```

jsp code :

```
operations op=new operations(); 
      product p=new product();
      List<product> list=op.getProducts();          
   %>

   <title>LG Mobiles</title>
  </head>
<body>
    <b><font color="blue">Total Records Fetched : <strong><%=list.size()%></strong></font></b>
```

QUERY is running fine in sql , i checked and confirmed

below is the small segment from setter getter class `product.java`

```
public void setPname(String pname)
{
  this.pname=pname;
}
public String getPname()
{
  return pname;
}
public void setPrice(String price)
{
  this.price=price;
}
public String getPrice()
{
  return price;
}
```

Comment: You are doing operations op = new Operations() and then accessing it. How are you getting dopata into op? You don't get data just by creating new operations() right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move prod.add(p); inside the while loop. As you are not adding object everytime. Also you need to create new object of p in loop everytime.

```
while(rs.next())
   {
  product p = new product();
  p.setPname(rs.getString(1));
  p.setPrice(rs.getString(2));
  p.setImg(rs.getString(3));
   prod.add(p);
  }
```

Comment: i tried it but it is not working .. same result ..(tried the object inside loop also)

Comment: Check your query if it is returning rows or not by directly running on  database

Comment: now it is returning records , but it is `iterating only the last record 3 times` !!

Comment: have you added this line in loop  product p = new product(); ??

Comment: i didn't get the point why do we need to create a new object in every iteration ... `but it is working FINE`

Comment: Because if you don't create new object every iteration, you will update the same object everytime and list will have reference to same object 3 times, having same value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82443/discussion-between-panther-and-amol-singh).

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove , from category and product using as

```
String sql="select product.product_name , product.price ,  product.image_url "
           + "from category as product "
           + "where product.category_id=category.category_id and   product.product_brand like 'LG%'"
```

or 
you also try this one

```
prod=cs.executeQuery(sql);
Iterator it=prod.iterator;

while(it.next())
{
---------------
}
```